# How to display rows of csv file in django?

Tags: django, pandas, django-tables2

I have a django app, which allows the user to upload a csv file, say a csv file of rankings of universities. I'd have to process the data that has been uploaded. For example, grey out any column which has string values and calculate the mean and std. deviation of all the values of a column. For this, I am using Pandas and converting the csv file to a pandas dataframe.

How do I display the dataset from the csv file using django? The column names cannot be hard coded because the user may upload any csv file. I checked django-tables2 and did the following

```
csvfile = request.FILES['csv_file']
data = pd.read_csv(csvfile.name)
context = {'loaded_data': data}
return render(request, "dataflow/table.html", context)
```

but I get the error `ValueError: Expected table or queryset, not DataFrame`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pandas dataframe can be converted to html table by itself. You can try

```
csvfile = request.FILES['csv_file']
data = pd.read_csv(csvfile.name)
data_html = data.to_html()
context = {'loaded_data': data_html}
return render(request, "dataflow/table.html", context)
```

In the html page, use `{{loaded_data | safe}}` to render the table.

Answer (score 2):

`django-tables2` can't handle `dataframes`. You have do convert it into something `django-tables2` understands, i.e.:

```
from django_tables2.tables import Table
```

in the view:

```
csvfile = request.FILES['csv_file']
data = pd.read_csv(csvfile.name)
df_table = Table(data.to_dict(orient='list'))
context = {'df_table': df_table}
return render(request, "dataflow/table.html", context)
```

in the template:

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% render_table df_table %}
```

This was a simple example, you might need do more work on the `dataframe` or even subclassing the [`Table`](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html) class.

Comment: I am getting `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'as_dict'`

Comment: my bad. the method is `to_dict`. Check the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) to see the possible return shapes.

Comment: Ok, that fixed it. But I still can't render the table. I have `</div>
                    {% render_table table_data %}
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm table-responsive table-condensed table-fixed">
                          <thead>
                          <tr>{% for item in table_data %}
                              <td>{{ item }}</td>
                          {% endfor %}</tr>` and I get the error `TypeError: 'Table' object is not iterable`

Comment: if you are using `django_tables2` render the table itself: `{% render_table df_table %}`. If you want more control over what is rendered, then you should think in a `Form` or something else.